# How to calculate derivative of complex matrix to this Frobenius norm?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, normed-spaces

I have a function $r = \|X - A\|^2_F$ and both $X$ and $A$ are $N\times N$ complex matrix. Could anyone show me how to calculate $\partial r/\partial X$?

Comment: What does the partial derivative with respect to a matrix mean?

Comment: It's probably reasonable to assume it's $2(X-A)$ or its conjugate given the isomorphism between this normed space and the related problem with the ordinary $l^2$ norm on $\Bbb{R}^{N^2}$ (My money is on the conjugate version unless this was asked by a machine learning heathen)

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it well. I just want to calculate $\partial r /\partial X$.

Comment: In fact, I want the modulus and phase of X to be similar to A's modulus and phase, respectively, so I add this regularization term r.

Comment: I just used the autograd function of pytorch to calculate the derivation. It seems to be the same with $2(X-A)$.

Comment: @LightMetal the problem with pytorch is that, you guessed it, it was designed by machine learning experts, not mathematicians. Sometimes the derivative is the transpose of what it needs to be and sometimes it is not. Some people in the field have tried to standardize notations but it has not been all that successful imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wiki page on matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) is a good cursory reference for this material. Note that there are two different common interpretations for the notation $\partial r/ \partial X$. If you are using this derivative for the purpose of gradient descent, then it is likely that you are after the denominator-layout derivative.

Running with that assumption, note that we can write
$$
\begin{align}
\|X - A\|^2 = \operatorname{tr}[(X - A)^T(X - A)] = \operatorname{tr}(X^TX) - 2 \operatorname{tr}(A^TX).
\end{align}
$$
Using [the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) on that same page, we find that
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial }{\partial X} \operatorname{tr}(X^TX) - 2\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \operatorname{tr}(A^TX) = 2(X - A).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations!